# How Can I enable SSO login to Apache Zeppelin on AWS EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, saml, apache-zeppelin

I created a AWS EMR Cluster using (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-launch.html, I chose the application  - "Spark: Spark 2.1.0 on Hadoop 2.7.3 YARN with Ganglia 3.7.2 and Zeppelin 0.7.0 while creating the cluster") and I am able to access Apache Zeppelin.

Now I want to give Zeppelin access to a new user using their Gmail or Google SSO or any other login. How can do this? Please point me to any documentation or steps.

*The SAML /SSO logins give access only to AWS console but not the application like Zeppelin which is hosted on the master node.

Answer (score 1):

Zeppelin uses

- [Apache Shiro](https://shiro.apache.org/)

and there are some libraries and examples to use oauth in shiro.

- [shiro-oauth](https://github.com/FeedTheCoffers/shiro-oauth)
- [Oauth2Relam.java](https://github.com/zhangkaitao/shiro-example/blob/master/shiro-example-chapter17-client/src/main/java/com/github/zhangkaitao/shiro/chapter18/oauth2/OAuth2Realm.java)
- [pac4j security library for Shiro: OAuth, CAS, SAML, OpenID Connect, LDAP, JWT...](https://github.com/bujiio/buji-pac4j)

But Zeppelin doens't support oauth extensions currently (0.8.0-SNAPSHOT) as far as i know. You might extend Zeppelin by yourself.

- [Docs: Zeppelin Shiro Configuration for Relam](http://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0-SNAPSHOT/security/shiroauthentication.html#configure-realm-optional)

Comment: Hi, I followed your instructions and used the above links to setup authentication using linkedin . But after the user is authenticated using linkedin, the control is not redirected to Zeppelin even though I give the defaultUrl as zeppelin url . Do I need to make any more configuration changes? Kindly help

Comment: @Srikanth I am also looking to implement the same for my use case. Is there a way to authenticate with user JWT token instead of asking for username/password, or bypass it anyhow?

Answer (score 0):

Single sign-on can be implemented using Apache Knox. KnoxSSO support is recently added to Zeppelin.

For configuration options check out this [link](https://medium.com/data-collective/apache-zeppelin-oauth-integration-using-apache-knox-dea2362e3dda)